# Binding images so they scroll horizontal not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, window

Just starting learning c# and windows phone, 
My Question I can't seem to get my images (Binding images) to show up and scroll horizontal, I can get them working if I hard code in xaml, here is the code I have...

```
<!-- row 4 start -->
    <Grid x:Name="row3" Grid.Row="3">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel x:Name="imgStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                <!--<Image Source="{Binding Path=DvdPhoto}" Width="150" Height="150"  Margin="5"/>-->

            <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/rain.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/snow.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/sun.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/wind.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/rain.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/snow.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/sun.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/wind.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/rain.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/snow.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/sun.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/wind.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/rain.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/snow.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/sun.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                <Image Source="/GmanDVDStore;component/Images/wind.jpg" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>

        </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

this works the images show up and I can scroll left to right, The commented out code where I have images binding does not work.

If I do it vertical it will work fine because I have in a listbox, and I have tried the listbox horizontal.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance

Gman

PS: go easy on me, as I said I am just starting to learn windows phone. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As referred in the answer to this question :

[WP7 - issues with Horizontal scrolling Listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558935/wp7-issues-with-horizontal-scrolling-listbox)

You can do this by specifying a value for the width of your ScrollViewer

Hope this will help somehow.

Comment: Still not work, here is the code `<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="Auto" Width="400">
<ListBox x:Name="lstBoxImgHor" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="200" >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Margin="5" x:Name="dvdStackPanelHor" Orientation="Horizontal">
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="img1" Source="{Binding Path=DvdPhoto}" Width="150" Height="150"  Margin="5"> </Image>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>`