# WP Horizontal Scrolling Grid Selection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create a scrollable gird, in my app i have a vertical scrolling listbox with text items as shown below.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="selectionList" Margin="49,0,11,0" Padding="20,20,0,0"      SelectionChanged="AlbumList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding ''}" Background="{x:Null}"      Height="606" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding SlectionTitle}" FontSize="22" Margin="0,0,0,10" FontFamily="{StaticResource hevel}" Foreground="#FF99FFFF"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

So I Changed The TextBlock to this

```
  <Border x:Name="Selection_List_Image" BorderBrush="#FFC4C3C3" BorderThickness="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="198" Margin="18,24,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="199" CornerRadius="12" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Padding="0">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding SelectionArt}"/>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
```

This is fine for a single vertical scrolling list. I'm trying to get a grid that is for example permanently 4 images high and automatically wide, so if there are 4 images it shows a column of 4 if there are 8 images it shows 2 columns of 4 and so on

i have tried this example
[WP7 - issues with Horizontal scrolling Listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558935/wp7-issues-with-horizontal-scrolling-listbox)

but it just kept the list vertical and scrolled horizontal

any suggestions, thanks

// Solved

Thank you, i ended up having to use the example link aswel

```
        <ListBox x:Name="AlbumList" Margin="49,0,11,0"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  SelectionChanged="AlbumList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding ''}" Background="{x:Null}" Height="748" >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" ></toolkit:WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border x:Name="Album_List_Image" BorderBrush="#FFC4C3C3" BorderThickness="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="152" Margin="18,24,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Center"  CornerRadius="12" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Padding="0" Width="152">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding AlbumArt}"/>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing WP8.1 runtime you can easily do this by changing the `<ItemsPanelTemplate>` to a `<WrapGrid>` with `Orientation` set to Vertical and `MaximumRowsOrColumns` set to 4.  Like so,

See [MSDN WrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid) (they actually do an example of what you want.. but in another Orientation)

```XAML
 <ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- your data template -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
</ListBox>
```

---

If you're doing this with WP8.0+ SL then it will be a tad bit harder.  You will need the Windows Phone Toolkit and use a `<WrapPanel>` instead but you will need to Databind some values (or hardcode it...depending on how loose your ViewModel is)

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Height="412">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" ItemHeight="100" ItemWidth="100"></toolkit:WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- your data template -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
</ListBox>
```

In this example I hard coded each Item to be 100x100 and I hard coded the Height to be 412, thus making it have 4 items in the Vertical.

You can Databind the `Height` and `ItemHeight` and the `ItemWidth` if you choose to do so.